# Packaging and auto-configuring custom icon for magento 2 module

Tags: magento, magento2

How do I configure a custom icon for magento 2 module? The tutorial that I find suggests creating a folder that is outside of the scope of the module package.

https://firebearstudio.com/blog/change-default-font-icon-in-magento-2.html

I want to be able to package the icon with the module and set it after the module is installed. Is it possible to achieve this?